# my model becomes translucent when I add automatic weights in blender (im completely new to blender)

Tags: animation, textures, blender

> I want to make a simple animation for a character but when I put the automatic weights the body becomes translucent [before putting the automatic weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtEkM.jpg)  [after putting the automatic weights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjd96.jpg)

because I am completely new to blender I have no idea what could cause this to happen